# How can I fix the VB comments and their formatting in questions that are tagged c#?

Tags: support, edits, code-formatting

As soon as a VB comment is in a code sample, the rest of the code formatting is messed up until the next comment (if there is another one).

Should we add a policy to escape comments with `'` so the code is better readable? Or should I go ahead and edit them in?

> [Good example of messed up code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38270027/1)

```
'this is a comment
this.Not
```

We could escape them like this:

```
'this is a comment'
this.Not
```

Because the css probably makes everything a char after a `'` and waits for the end.

It is also a problem that comments sometimes look like code after, and it's really hard to read VB code because of that.

What could be a solution to this problem?

Comment: That "good example" is tagged with `c#`, so it's using `c#` formatting, not VB. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: After rene's edit, it looks pretty good. Remember that language detection is not automatic, it can be derived from the tag (in this case C#), but if you have 'mixed' content, you need to give Prettify a little hint.

Comment: @Glorfindel oh ye it does, thanks a lot. Didn't know about the language tags`!

Comment: It is just a bug in Google's parser, it has been around for ever.  It interprets the comment as a string literal.  The simple workaround is to use 2 quotes, `'' this is a comment`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is too much going on in that post. It has C#, VB.NET and XAML markup.

And now you expect magically that the code prettifier makes sense of that? The developers here are more than great but they didn't master this ... yet.

The [syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) takes the language hint from the tag. As c# is the main tag, all code blocks will use the lang-cs prettifier.

I've added a `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` at the start of the VB.NET block to tell the prettifier that it needs to use lang-vb instead of the post default.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the problem was the language tags, but this happens legitimately.

This highly up voted [Perl & regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843579/6083675) illustrates this perfectly. It is using the proper highlighting, but the second half of the code is using string highlighting. I'm not sure if this is the type of "obfuscated code" Google Prettify meant when they said:

> **It doesn't work on <obfuscated code sample>?**
>
> Yes. Prettifying obfuscated code is like putting lipstick on a pig — i.e. outside the scope of this tool

(Don't listen to them, regexes can be beautiful.)

I find this behavior extremely annoying. As long as it doesn't change the meaning of the code, it will improve the readability of the code, and thus would be a good edit (but probably too risky for a suggestion).

---

It seems you were a little too late with your suggestion. [VB comment highlighting was a problem back in 2008.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149726/6083675)